# Starting MSTest Controller Service along side Jenkins service

Tags: jenkins, mstest

We recently ran into an issue recently where our MS Test Controller controller service failed to start along side Jenkins service. Every time we attempt to start the controller service, we the following error in the event log

```
Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/AgentInstallerService/ because TCP port 80 is being used by another application. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpe...

Has anyone run into this before?
```

Answer (score 1):

We saw this same error, and it was caused by Visual Studio trying to start a TestController/Agent using port 80, with Jenkins also running on that port.  Our solution was to update Jenkins to run on port 8080.  This was accomplished by updating our Jenkins config as follows:

D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml (could be located somewhere else)

-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080

This would presumably also occur if any other (non-Jenkins) services were already running on Port 80.